# How to get input from mentioned user with discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add a marry command for my discord.py bot that I have recently started programming. I want the mentioned user to be able to respond back to the bot.

As of the code right now, It only replies back to me.

```
@client.command()
async def marry(ctx, member: discord.Member):

    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} **proposes to** {member.mention} **Do you accept??** "
                   f"\nRespond with [y(es)/n(o)]")

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author

    try:
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=10)

        if msg.content.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
            await ctx.send(f"Congratulations! {ctx.author.mention} and {member.mention} are now married to each other!")
        elif  msg.content.lower() in ['n', 'no']:
            await ctx.send(f"Unlucky, maybe another time! {ctx.author.mention}")
        else:
            await ctx.send("I did not understand that, aborting!")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
        print(e)
        await ctx.send("Looks like you waited too long.")
```

Does anyone know how to make it so that the bot can recognise the next reply from the mentioned user (member: discord.Member) instead of just me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your check, you can simply check if the message's author is the same as the member that's being passed into the command's arguments:

```py
def check(m):
    return m.author == member
```

I'd also recommend adding in another check for the same channel that the command was executed in.

This'll prevent the bot from picking up replies from other conversations the mentioned user is having that may be unrelated:

```py
def check(m):
    return ... and m.channel == ctx.channel
```

---

**References:**

- [`Message.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel)
- [`Context.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.channel)